# Logistic Regression for Numerical data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I have these labels and features like

```
labels features
 [2.3]   1 5.1 7.2 5 5 5
 [5.4]   4.5 3 2 4 6 4
 [6.3]   3.3 1.3 5.4 6
```

Like this, I have more than 10K entries. How can I use Logistic regression to train a model in spark?
I know we can use linear regression. But still, I want to use LogisticReg to check it's performance.
Till now what I did was mapping those classes to discrete values like `(2.3->0,5.4->1, 6.3->2)`
I have found 11101 unique labels. But computation taking a lot of time.

Comment: Logistic regression is used for classification problems, so it doesn't make much sense to use logistic regression if your labels are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Those labels you have seem to be continuous variables (and not discrete). As far as I know, logistic regression in Spark can be only used for classification, and not for regressions (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html).